# Running Python Code on Knime's Python Script Node

Tags: knime

I am fairly new to Knime and Python and I was checking some codes in Python that I would like to run on Python Script Node through Knime. The script executes fine through the node but not outside it, plus, the data does not show correctly on output panel for "Poisson Model" attribute on following script:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn
from scipy.stats import poisson,skellam
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf


epl_1617 = input_table


poisson_model = smf.glm(formula="input_table['GOALS'] ~ 
input_table['HOME'] + input_table['HomeTeam'] + 
input_table['AwayTeam']", data=epl_1617, 
                    family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()

poisson_model.summary()
```

When I run the above code on Python it gives the result in form of a table; however, in Knime the output is shown as "poisson_model:
"

Note: the input file can be downloaded from:

http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1617/E0.csv

Any idea on how to run the following code on Knime?

I have tried assigning the result to a DataFrame using the following:

```
output_table = pd.DataFrame(poisson_model.summary())
```

However, I have been getting the following error:

```
output_table = pd.DataFrame(poisson_model.summary())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\KNIME\plugins\org.knime.python2_3.6.0.v201807061638\py\PythonKernelBase.py", line 278, in execute
exec(source_code, self._exec_env, self._exec_env)
 File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 422, 
 in __init__
   raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
 ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

and here is the result if I run the same code using Python IDE

```
poisson_model.summary()
Out[3]: 
<class 'statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary'>
"""
                 Generalized Linear Model Regression Results                  
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  GOALS   No. Observations:                  740
Model:                            GLM   Df Residuals:                      700
Model Family:                 Poisson   Df Model:                           39
Link Function:                    log   Scale:                          1.0000
Method:                          IRLS   Log-Likelihood:                -1107.5
Date:                Wed, 27 Mar 2019   Deviance:                       906.20
Time:                        19:29:22   Pearson chi2:                     784.
No. Iterations:                     5   Covariance Type:             nonrobust
==============================================================================================
                                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept                      0.4226      0.193      2.190      0.029       0.044       0.801
HomeTeam[T.Bournemouth]        0.1726      0.188      0.917      0.359      -0.196       0.542
HomeTeam[T.Burnley]           -0.1755      0.208     -0.845      0.398      -0.582       0.232
HomeTeam[T.Chelsea]            0.2356      0.187      1.259      0.208      -0.131       0.602
HomeTeam[T.Crystal Palace]    -0.0903      0.201     -0.450      0.652      -0.483       0.303
HomeTeam[T.Everton]            0.0608      0.192      0.317      0.752      -0.316       0.437
HomeTeam[T.Hull]               0.0676      0.195      0.347      0.729      -0.315       0.450
HomeTeam[T.Leicester]          0.0599      0.196      0.306      0.760      -0.324       0.444
HomeTeam[T.Liverpool]          0.1453      0.191      0.760      0.447      -0.229       0.520
HomeTeam[T.Man City]           0.0060      0.196      0.031      0.975      -0.378       0.390
HomeTeam[T.Man United]        -0.3528      0.218     -1.616      0.106      -0.781       0.075
HomeTeam[T.Middlesbrough]     -0.3185      0.212     -1.505      0.132      -0.733       0.096
HomeTeam[T.Southampton]       -0.3345      0.217     -1.545      0.122      -0.759       0.090
HomeTeam[T.Stoke]             -0.1255      0.202     -0.623      0.533      -0.521       0.269
HomeTeam[T.Sunderland]        -0.0894      0.199     -0.448      0.654      -0.480       0.302
HomeTeam[T.Swansea]            0.1140      0.193      0.592      0.554      -0.264       0.491
HomeTeam[T.Tottenham]          0.0301      0.194      0.155      0.877      -0.350       0.410
HomeTeam[T.Watford]           -0.0352      0.201     -0.175      0.861      -0.429       0.358
HomeTeam[T.West Brom]         -0.1100      0.200     -0.549      0.583      -0.503       0.283
HomeTeam[T.West Ham]          -0.0738      0.200     -0.370      0.712      -0.465       0.317
AwayTeam[T.Bournemouth]       -0.0941      0.182     -0.517      0.605      -0.451       0.263
AwayTeam[T.Burnley]           -0.3271      0.190     -1.722      0.085      -0.699       0.045
AwayTeam[T.Chelsea]           -0.3465      0.192     -1.801      0.072      -0.724       0.031
AwayTeam[T.Crystal Palace]    -0.0285      0.177     -0.161      0.872      -0.376       0.319
AwayTeam[T.Everton]           -0.3461      0.195     -1.777      0.076      -0.728       0.036
AwayTeam[T.Hull]              -0.1969      0.184     -1.071      0.284      -0.557       0.163
AwayTeam[T.Leicester]         -0.1790      0.183     -0.978      0.328      -0.537       0.180
AwayTeam[T.Liverpool]         -0.1381      0.181     -0.762      0.446      -0.493       0.217
AwayTeam[T.Man City]          -0.0412      0.179     -0.230      0.818      -0.392       0.309
AwayTeam[T.Man United]        -0.3990      0.194     -2.061      0.039      -0.778      -0.020
AwayTeam[T.Middlesbrough]     -0.5297      0.206     -2.574      0.010      -0.933      -0.126
AwayTeam[T.Southampton]       -0.2731      0.187     -1.463      0.143      -0.639       0.093
AwayTeam[T.Stoke]             -0.2855      0.190     -1.502      0.133      -0.658       0.087
AwayTeam[T.Sunderland]        -0.3859      0.198     -1.950      0.051      -0.774       0.002
AwayTeam[T.Swansea]           -0.1941      0.184     -1.056      0.291      -0.554       0.166
AwayTeam[T.Tottenham]         -0.2569      0.190     -1.351      0.177      -0.630       0.116
AwayTeam[T.Watford]           -0.2025      0.184     -1.102      0.270      -0.563       0.158
AwayTeam[T.West Brom]         -0.3953      0.198     -1.998      0.046      -0.783      -0.008
AwayTeam[T.West Ham]          -0.0867      0.180     -0.480      0.631      -0.440       0.267
HOME                           0.2962      0.063      4.695      0.000       0.173       0.420
==============================================================================================
"""
```

Your help is already appreciated!

Comment: It looks as if the `.summary()` method you're using just prints a human-readable summary to the console. To return output from Python to KNIME you need to assign it to a pandas DataFrame named `output_table` (or `output_table_1` and `output_table_2` for a 2-output node). Can you mock up an example of what you want the table returned to KNIME to look like?

Comment: Following your edit: I'm still not sure what you're expecting the output returned to KNIME to look like. A DataFrame and a KNIME table are both intended to hold tabular data, with one or more columns ('variables' in DataFrame terms) and one or more rows. The `summary()` output doesn't fit that format. Do you want to use this data for some further calculation in KNIME? If so I think you need to add Python code to retrieve the specific data you want from your `poisson_model` object into appropriate variables in `output_table`.

Comment: When you say 'the same code' in your Python IDE gives the summary output, does that include the `output_table = pd.DataFrame(poisson_model.summary())` assignment?